# Is VSC not compatible with .net core 2 projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, .NET Core SDK Preview 2.0.0 (006497), VSC 1.14.2

Things used to work fine under .net core 1. Now, I have upgraded my system to .net core 2.

From the command line, I created a new project and ran it:

```
$ dotnet new mvc
$ dotnet run
```

The webpage works as expected.

Now, I open the folder in VSC and tried to debug the app. First time, VCS helps create `launch.json` and `tasks.json.` Here is my `tasks.json` contents:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the terminal view, I see that VCS tries to run the build command as `dotnet <`. This throws an error that preLaunchTask "build" exited with error code 129.

I tried to fix this by adding `args: ["build"]` to the task. This seems to fix the build but I now get another error about launch.json not being configured properly.

Wondering if there is some step that I simply missed. Regards.

Comment: the most relevant information is at the bottom https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0-preview2-known-issues.md. Basically says if **want** to try .netcore 2 on VSC then **try** this...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Installing the beta version of C# extension did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by mvermef in his comment. I am just adding a new post here so I can mark it as an answer.

The problems with VSC are explained at https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.0/2.0.0-preview2-known-issues.md. The most important thing is that you remove your existing C# extension and replace it with the latest beta version. Now, if you create a new project from the command line and load it in VSC, you should be able to debug it.